# jQuery show delete display attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm using jQuery hide and show function but I have a problem with the show one.

My javascript code is:

```
function toggle_visibility(idContent, idLien, question) {
    var c = document.getElementById(idContent);
    var l = document.getElementById(idLien);
    var q = question;
    if(c.style.display == 'block') {
        $("#" + idContent).hide("blind") ;
        l.innerHTML = '<h4><i class=\"icone-rouge icon-right-open-big\"></i>'+ q +'</h4>' ;
    }
    else {
        $("#" + idContent).show("blind") ;
        l.innerHTML = '<h4><i class=\"icone-rouge icon-down-open-big\"></i>'+ q +'</h4>' ;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for the hide part when the div is hidden at the load of the page (with display='none'). I can display the block but then I cannot hide it.

I noticed that when I show a content, jQuery delete the display attr in my html style... Maybe there is a link.

Here a link for example : http://jsfiddle.net/29c4D/2/

Thank you.

Comment: Why use plain JS if you're using jQuery (e.g. `document.getElementById(idLien);`)? You can shorten your code a good amount by using jQuery properly.

Comment: Because I'm a beginner with jQuery and that I use that as complement. I don't use a lot of jQuery. It's not an good reason, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DescampsAu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904080/descampsau), since you are using jQuery I rewrote your code to take full advantage of the powerful library. You can see the example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthew1/29c4D/6/).

Let jQuery do the heavy lifting of checking whether an element is hidden or not by making use of either the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [.slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) methods.

Remove all of the onClick() code within your spans and use this jQuery instead:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    //After the page has loaded, let jQuery know where all of the spans are.
    var toggleThis = $(".toggleMe");

    //Whenever you click one of the spans do this function.
    toggleThis.click( function() {
        //Register the span you clicked and the next div that holds the hidden stuffs.
        var el = $(this),
            nextDiv = el.next(".toggleMeDiv");

        //Check if the span's partner div is hidden or showing by checking its css "display" value.
        if(nextDiv.css("display") == "block") {
            //Change the text of the span to be its title attribute plus whether its partner is showing or hidden.
            el.html(el.attr("title")+" hidden");
        } else {
            el.text(el.attr("title")+" shown");
        }

        //Let jQuery toggle the partner's visibility.
        nextDiv.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="toggleMe" title="Quest 1">Quest 1</span>
<div class="toggleMeDiv">Boubou1</div>

<span class="toggleMe" title="Quest 2">Quest 2</span>
<div class="toggleMeDiv">Boubou2</div>
```

Comment: The link of your fiddle is wrong. It is my fiddle I posted in my post. However, I tried your code and it works. But the second question is next to the first when this latter is hidden. And I don't know how to change the question label.

Comment: The spans are next to each other because I gave the wrong fiddle link :p I fixed that now and you should be able to see it in action. I also added the ability to update the labels by reading the span title.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You are really helpful! I will try to understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

Making this too hard on yourself.

**HTML**

```
<span class="toggle" id="lien1" data-original-text="Quest 1">Quest 1</span>
<div id="content1">Boubou1</div>

<span class="toggle" id="lien2" data-original-text="Quest 1">Quest 2</span>
<div  id="content2">Boubou2</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('div').toggle('blind', textToggle); // or slideToggle();
    });


    function textToggle() {
        var $target = $(this).prev('span'); // "this" is the div that was toggled.
        var originalText = $target.attr('data-original-text');

        if ( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
            $target.text(  originalText + ' open' );    
        } else {
            $target.text( originalText + ' closed' );
        }   
    }
});
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29c4D/7/

**EDIT** to include label + effect.

Comment: His changing the text in labels.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But how to keep the visual effect? And how to change my   label?

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation Will. Our code is almost the same except that you use a custom attribute while I rely on the 'title' attribute. Your answer prompted me to try that out in a page I was working on yesterday. Custom attributes are really helpful.